# Where do the line numbers point to in Java stacktraces printed by exceptions thrown by code from jars that have no source code jar attached

Tags: java, stack-trace

When an exception is thrown by code that is compiled within a jar that doesn't have a source jar attached to it, do the line numbers in the stacktrace refer to the line numbers of the bytecode statements in the compiled class, or somehow the line number in the class containing the source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you compile Java code, the line numbers of the source are by default written into the bytecode. This makes it easier to track down problems. The line number (and source file) information is stored in the `.class` file, and is not (necessarily) the same as the line in attached sources. For example, if you attach the sources of the wrong version of a library, then you might be shown the wrong line when debugging.

It is possible to disable this (eg by passing `-g:none` to `javac`). Disabling this will make it a lot harder to locate and troubleshoot problems, but disabling it will make the resulting `.class` smaller.

Comment: so are you saying that if a particular line `throw new Exception();` is in a java file named `Main.java` at line 100, and i convert that file into a jar file, add it to a project, and the statement is executed, the line number for the exception in the stacktrace will be 100 and not something else?

Comment: @thebeest Yes, attaching source code to your project has nothing to do with, as this information is part of the `.class`-file.